# Does the var becomes a function because of a javascript function stored in a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

In below example about [Scope](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/), I dont understand that how could a variable is running as a function? in here `var f` is running as `f()`. However, is this a sound method to run `f` in JavaScript? Why? Is it because `var f` stored a function?

```
var myFunction = function() {
  var foo = "hello";
  var myFn = function() {
    console.log( foo );
  };
  foo = "ddd";
  return myFn;
};
var f = myFunction();
f(); // "ddd"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will run the function `myFunction` and assign its return value to f.

```
var f = myFunction();
```

`myFunction` returns a reference to the function `myFn`. As a result, f is now a reference to `myFn` and when you attempt to call `f` using `f()` it calls `myFn` because that is where the reference points.

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8bap6/)***

There is a similar approach which returns an object with functions

```
var init = function(){
 return {
  hello: function(){ console.log("hello"); },
  world: function(){ console.log("world"); }
 };
};
```

Which could then be used like this:

```
var f = init();
f.hello();
f.world();
```

Comment: What is a "reference point"? Is it because its the first variable that is a function for myFunction()?

Comment: @Chen - In javascript, references are pointers. So when you return a function you are returning a pointer to that function. Essentially it means that whatever gets assigned that pointer will act just like `myFunction` will act.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects in javascript, so they can be assigned to variables and passed around like any other value.  And eventually they can be executed.

What's happening here is that `myFunction` *returns* a function, which can then of course be executed.

Let me simplify your example:

```
// function that returns a function.
var foo = function() {

  // declare a function, but don't run it right now.
  var fn = function() {
    return "bar";
  };

  // return the function object.
  return fn;
}

var someFn = foo(); // function object is returned from foo()
someFn();           // "bar" is returned

// Which means you could also do this!
// the first () executes foo, second () executes the function returned by foo()
foo()()             // "bar" is returned
```

In this example, `foo()` returns a function.  This function is saved to the local variable `someFn` and then executed.

Functions that return functions are a little tricky to wrap you head around sometimes, but it's one of the most powerful features of javascript as it allows you do some very tricky things.

Comment: I kinda get it but kinda lost as well lol. 1. When you say "// the first () executes foo, second () executes the function returned by foo()" do you mean that the 2nd() executes someFn this case? 2. In this case, 'return fn' has the same effect as 'fun()', does it? since fn() itself returns a value to foo() and then foo return the value of fn() as itself's value to the main?

Answer (score 0):

In scripting languages in general and functional programming. You can use functions as you would a variable. For example: in both paradigms typically(not aware of any languages that don't) functions can be passed as parameters, etc...